# Children divs of a parent grid do not fill all the available space

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I have this setup in which i need the form, the button and the select box to occupy all the availabe space horizontally. In small screen sizes all works as intended

[image: small creen size]

however when I test it in bigger screens all the space is not filled by the child elements [image: bigger screen size]

I tried both grid and flex->row approaches with the same result. How do i fix my code that even in bigger size the child elements fill all the available space horizontally with equal spaces between them?

```css
.grand-parent {
  margin-top: 2%;
  left: 0%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.parent {
  min-width: 395px;
  position: relative;
  /* display: flex;
  flex-direction: row; */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1 fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  padding-left: 5%;
  justify-content: space-between;

}

.child {
  background-color: blue;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 24px;
  align-self: center;

}
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details. CSS alone is useless in most cases without its corresponding HTML markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have one row and want all children to be the same size, then the usual approach for me would be to use `display: flex` on the parent and `flex-grow: 1; flex-basis: 0` on the children. No need for `flex-direction: row`. Also make sure that the parent is actually the width you expect, i.e. it also fills the whole width.

Comment: flex-grow will not make all child elements the same width. It will distribute all remaining space equally. The width of the child elements is still calculated to the content. the input type number (bet amount) is about 1.5 times wider than the button after it and as such the base width is longer.

Comment: @Fabian Sievert thanks for the clarification. Your comment about the parent not being the width i expect was spot on. I was overwriting its style somewhere else in jsx styles